# Нейросеть для векторов размером 360(радар). Подскажите базовую архитектуру для доработок

Tags: нейронные-сети, keras

Всем хелоу.

Прилетела сферическая задача научить "робота" с радаром определять где же он. Если опустить все подробности то в сухом остатке мы имеем следующее:

- есть набор векторов размером в 360 и значениями от 0. до 0.4500 (примерно, погрешность радара плавает).
- имеющее достаточно уникальный в оси Х рельеф помещение разбито на 10 условных секторов и в каждом из них были сняты показания радара по 10000 раз (если надо больше то легко)
- на каждый вектор снятых данных(это массив размером 360 где значением является расстояние до приграды) "варится" еще по по 3, где этот вектор поворачивается по 90 градусов(т.е. 90,180,270 возможна реализация других трансформаций данных, например, масштаб или сдвиг)
- т.к. помещение было разбито на 10 секторов то задача определить к какому из 10 секторов относится "слепок" с радара (т.е. вектор размером 360).

Что было сделано:

- ну да, разбил помещение на 10 "образных" секторов
- и конечно, сделал замеры по 10к раз с каждого из них
- козалось бы, но написал "подготовку данных" где мы крутим каждый снятый вектор на 90 градусов
- и что не мало важно, смог за пару дней "раскурить" keras и извоять там  простую сеть LSTM в 4 слоя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.к. никто не разбирается в "нейросетевой" архитектуре был взят один из примеров кластирезации из гугл-источника

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
           input_shape=(1, 360)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Сетке были скормлены более 200000 замеренных с 10 секторов векторов + их обработка с поворотом по 90 градусов, в качестве "учителя" были даны варианты правильного определения( [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] например для определения 2го сектора и [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] для определения последнего, остальные включительно)

После 10-20 эпох резултат впечатлил, 99% val_acc и любой пердикшен выдает как буддто знает к какому сектору относится вектор, и на 90, 180,270 тоже и на +/- 2 градуса но...

стоит повернуть практически любой вектор через np.roll более чем на 3-4 грудса от векторов на которых обучалась сеть то сразу получаем ошибку определения класса.

Вопрос: **Подскажите примерную, базовую архитектуру сети которая бы принимала фигуру(n, 1, 360) и при обучении "крепчала" не от того что ей показывают тысячи вариантов векторов повернутых по 1 градусу с каждого сектора, а была бы способна выявлять признаки "не особо" зависящие от поворота**

Answer (score 3):

Я бы первым делом исключил вращение, насколько получится, чтобы не кормить НС лишними данными. Нужна какая-то функция, которая для каждой картины радара будет более-менее однозначно определять нулевую точку. В данной задаче, как для меня выглядит ее специфика, это более реально, чем, например, компенсация вращения символа в капче.

Немного дополняю ответ. Компенсация вращения это подготовка входных данных (не обучающих). Этим исключается необходимость для нейросети научиться вращать входной вектор самостоятельно. Даже если функция, определяющая точку отсчета входного вектора дает сбои, то это проявляется лишь в нескольких сдвинутых вариантах входного вектора при одних и тех же координатах робота. Это все равно намного экономней 360 вариантов на каждый по сути один и тот же входной вектор за вычетом сдвига.

Похожий подход следует применить и для выходных данных. А именно, выход - это два блока сигналов. Например, вы хотите чтобы определялись коородинаты робота по x и y. Все пространство делится на сетку, например, 1000x1000. У НС будет 2000 выходов. Таким образом исключается необходимость для нейросети учиться формировать двоичные числа.

Comment: не совсем понял как можно исключить вращение если робот с радаром может находиться/перемещаться под любым произвольным углом/углами в помещении.

Comment: и определить в какую сторону он повернут не представляется возможным

Comment: Не нужно определять, в какую сторону он повернут. Можно попробовать свернуть входной вектор с функцией Гаусса или sinc. Потом позицию в векторе, значение в которой максимально, брать за точку отсчета. Если затруднительно определить максимум, можно искать минимум. Если не получается с минимумом, можно ориентироваться по значению и производной как советский осциллограф.

Comment: я так понимаю ваш ответ подразумевает что нет такого набора слоев keras и их конфигураций что бы решить задачу компенсации вращения векторов данных as is без "глубоких" познаний математики и предварительной обработки данных перед подачей НС.

Comment: Вообще-то в матане нейросетей доказывается, что обычный перцептрон может делать вообще что угодно. Вопрос в количестве нейронов, и сколько локальных экстремумов ошибки придется пройти (и как) при обучении.

Comment: Вроде бы по Розенблатту перцептрон как раз не может решать задачи в контексте которых присутствует поворот или это относится исключительно к 3х слойным перцептронам?

Comment: Ваша идея понятна, только в том случае, если допустить что способ когда каждый входящий вектор есть возможность отнести к одному и тому же ярко выраженому координату, некой точки отсчета. Обсудив с коллегой мы поняли что не имеем возможности в силу теххнических и теоритических ограничений, компас, находясь в окружении мощных акквмуляторов и плат управления представляет скорее опасность, любой другой, нам доступный, датчик так же бесполезен. Как определить математически для тысяч входящих векторов, разных, имеющих ничего не говорящие минимумы и максимумы во все стороны, кто у них первый?

Comment: Я скорее имею в виду что нуждаюсь в чуть более подробном развороте ответа. Я не являюсь специалистом в данном направлении.

Comment: Для вашей сети, которая есть сейчас: попробуйте обучать ее векторами, вращаемыми под всеми углами, а не только 90/180/270. Что касается той идеи - это НЕ КОМПАС, а немного меньше, чем компас. Просто нужно, чтобы независимо от угла поворота робота в одной и той же точке вектор всегда подавался на вход сети под одним и тем же углом (либо под набором углов) - НЕ ВАЖНО, ПОД КАКИМ(И) ИМЕННО.

Comment: Если будете использовать быстрое преобразование Фурье для сглаживания вектора (например, свертка с sinc), то, поскольку вектор периодический, есть возможность автоматически усреднять, перелезая за край (для получения значения в точке 359 будут будут использоваться значения из точек 0, 1, 2..., а не только 358, 357, 356...). Для любого такого сглаженного вектора для одной точки расположения робота (но под разными направлениями), если в сглаженном векторе есть явный максимум (к примеру), то по нему можно и ориентироваться.

Comment: То есть берем максимум сглаженного вектора и вращаем несглаженный исходник на позицию, в которой находится тот максимум. Подаем в таком виде на вход сети. И при обучении, и при распознавании. Если для конкретного вектора нет явного максимума, пробуем использовать минимум. Если нет явного минимума, то пробуем использовать какую-нибудь жесть типа точки пересечения с линией, соответствующей среднему арифметическому значений вектора, в которой производная максимальна.